# windows key in emacs in -nw mode

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-10.04, gnome-terminal

I add the following line to my ~/.emacs

(global-set-key (kbd "") 'other-window)

It works on emacs GUI mode. But if I open emacs in terminal (Ubuntu 10.04) with the option

-nw, then  <kbd>Win + Right</kbd> just give <kbd>right</kbd>. I tried many key

combinations with the windows key, it seems that windows key doesn't function in the

terminal. I guess that the default terminal in Ubuntu doesn't recognize teh <kbd>Win</kbd>

key at all. If I want to use <kbd>Win</kbd> key in the terminal, I have modify the source

code of termianl. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The win key under ubuntu becomes the modifier Super, I don't think that the terminal recognizes this as a key modifier. You could switch the windows key to something else or just use ctrl or meta keys.

Comment: @ Jesus Ramos: Thanks. You said it becomes the modifier super, but you said the terminal doesn't recognizes this as a key modifier? So "the modifier super" is not a "key modifier"? (Sorry, maybe this is stupid, but I don't understand it well...)

Comment: Yeah sorry I explained it a little odd. The Super key is a modifier but only for the OS, unlike meta/alt and ctrl which can act as key modifiers for special characters or for performaing actions Ctrl-C interrupts current terminal command etc... alt/meta+key = special characters. super + key is mostly just for program shortcuts, ex. in ubuntu super + tab is a fancy version of alt+tab. Hope this clears some things up.